# How to replay basic High Low game?

Tags: java

I am almost finished with my second Java assignment for class, but I am stuck on how to take the user's last choice and either play again or quit. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HighLow {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int answer = randomNumber.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userGuess = null;
        boolean gameWin = false;

        do {
            while (!gameWin) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game, guess a number between 1 - 100 or type 'quit' to exit: ");
                userGuess = userInput.nextLine();
                numberOfTries++;


                if (userGuess.equals("quit"))
                    break;
                if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) == answer) {
                    gameWin = true;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) > answer) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
                }

            }

            if (userGuess.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("You choose to quit! Thanks for playing");
                System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
            System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
            System.out.println("You win! Play again(type: yes or no)");


        }
        while (userGuess.equals("yes"));
            userInput.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you have `userInput.nextLine()` prompt for the user to play again or not outside of the game loop and it isn't assigned to any value. I am referring to this section...

```
        System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
        System.out.println("You win! Play again(type: yes or no)");


    }
    while (userGuess.equals("yes"));
        userInput.nextLine();  <---
    }
```

To fix this problem you simply need to assign the final input call to `userGuess` and place it back into the game loop like so.

```
        System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
        System.out.println("You win! Play again(type: yes or no)");

        userGuess = userInput.nextLine();
    }
    while (userGuess.equals("yes"));
    }
```

Doing this will assign the `play again` value you prompt the user for into the variable that your testing with the `do-while`loop. In your original, you had the condition testing for a value that `userGuess` wasn't going to be storing and instead prompting the user for that option AFTER the loop would have been exited instead of inside where it needs to be.

To reset the values for the next game, you can simply move the variables' initialization into the game loop at the top like so...

```
import java.util.Random;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
public class HighLow {

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int numberOfTries, answer;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userGuess;
    boolean gameWin;

    do {
        answer = randomNumber.nextInt(100) + 1;
        gameWin = false;
        userGuess = null;
        numberOfTries = 0;

        while (!gameWin) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game, guess a number between 1 - 100 or type 'quit' to exit: ");
            userGuess = userInput.nextLine();
            numberOfTries++;


            if (userGuess.equals("quit"))
                break;
            if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) == answer) {
                gameWin = true;
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) < answer) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) > answer) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            }

        }

        if (userGuess.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("You choose to quit! Thanks for playing");
            System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
        System.out.println("You win! Play again(type: yes or no)");

        userGuess = userInput.nextLine();
    }
    while (userGuess.equals("yes"));

    }
}
}
```

this way every time the game loops through, all the values will be reset at the beginning of the new game loop.

Also you should close the `Random` object and `Scanner` object at the end of the entire program using `close()` on each instance.

Comment: Thanks, but this Loops the game that has already been played and prints out the number you guessed. I need it to reset the values.

Comment: @CameronMcTaggart Please reference my revisions to answer your question about reseting values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize most of your variables and call `userInput.nextLine();` inside your outer loop. Untested suggestion:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HighLow {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        String userGuess = null;

        do {
            Random randomNumber = new Random();
            int answer = randomNumber.nextInt(100) + 1;
            int numberOfTries = 0;
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean gameWin = false;
            while (!gameWin) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game, guess a number between 1 - 100 or type 'quit' to exit: ");
                userGuess = userInput.nextLine();
                numberOfTries++;


                if (userGuess.equals("quit"))
                    break;
                if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) == answer) {
                    gameWin = true;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(userGuess) > answer) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
                }

            }

            if (userGuess.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("You choose to quit! Thanks for playing");
                System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
            System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries");
            System.out.println("You win! Play again(type: yes or no)");


        }
        userInput.nextLine();
        while (userGuess.equals("yes"));
        }
    }
}
```